# Dart JS 0.6 interrop with Leafletjs resulting in type error

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I am trying to use LeafletJS from Dart using the js 0.6.0 interrop library. I have created the following Dart file to map the construction of a basic Leaflet map.

```dart
@JS("L")
library leaflet;

import "dart:html";
import "package:js/js.dart";

@JS("map")
class LeafletMap {
   external factory LeafletMap(Element element);
}
```

I then *use* these classes in my main.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:charm/leaflet.dart';

main() {
   var e = querySelector("#map");
   var m = new LeafletMap(e);
}
```

This would be equivalent to the Javascript below which would create and display a map with default configuration.

```js
var map = L.map('map');
```

The HTML looks like the following and includes the leaflet.js javascript file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>

  <script src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following error is displayed in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: L.map is not a function
```

However, if I use the console directly in the browser, L.map exists as a function. Not sure if I'm using the JS interrop library correctly and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I don't know Leaflet. Can you elaborate a bit more what you actually try to accomplish? `factory` constructor is to create a Dart class that can be passed to JS. AFAIR there is no need to create a wrapper class to pass a DOM element to JS (`#map`).

Comment: I have added an example of the equivalent JS. I had created a factory method as the Leaflet call to create a map appears to be just a JS method call on the namespace L that return a new object. This approach might not be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You face an [known issue](http://dartbug.com/25318) that is basically about collisions with minified dart2js names.

Comment: The name collision was the main problem. Changed Leaflet namespace away from L to Leaflet and existing code worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want

```
@JS("L")
library leaflet;

import "dart:html";
import "package:js/js.dart";

@JS("map")
external map(String str);
```

I don't know what the function returns though.